# How do i solve the "Provider not available. Use `.setProvider` or `.provider=` to initialize the provider". uncaught runtime error?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, truffle, decentralized-applications

I am new to Dapp development. I tried creating a Dapp using truffle. I followed this link [https://docs.infura.io/tutorials/ethereum/create-a-dapp-using-truffle-and-react](https://stackoverflow.com).
After successfully running the local server (step 7 of building the web3 frontend), i am unable to interact with the smart contract. I get an error when I click the button to interact with the contract.
[Uncaught runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4XOh.jpg)

Storage.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;
contract Storage {
    string text;
    function store(string memory a) public {
        text = a;
    }
    function retrieve() public view returns (string memory ){
        return text;
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Storage } from "./abi/abi";
import Web3 from "web3";
import "./App.css";

// Access our wallet inside of our dapp
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
// Contract address of the deployed smart contract
const contractAddress = "0x088213adCC8F391Ae23961084A0bb888F09D669a";
const storageContract = new web3.eth.Contract(Storage, contractAddress);

function App() {
  // Hold variables that will interact with our contract and frontend
  const [number, setUint] = useState(0);
  const [getNumber, setGet] = useState("0");

  const numberSet = async (t) => {
    t.preventDefault();
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
    const account = accounts[0];
    // Get permission to access user funds to pay for gas fees
    const gas = await storageContract.methods.store(number).estimateGas();
    const post = await storageContract.methods.store(number).send({
      from: account,
      gas,
    });
  };

  const numberGet = async (t) => {
    t.preventDefault();
    const post = await storageContract.methods.retrieve().call();
    setGet(post);
  };

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="card">
        <form className="form" onSubmit={numberSet}>
          <label>
            Set your uint256:
            <input
              className="input"
              type="text"
              name="name"
              onChange={(t) => setUint(t.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <button className="button" type="submit" value="Confirm">
            Confirm
          </button>
        </form>
        <br />
        <button className="button" onClick={numberGet} type="button">
          Get your uint256
        </button>
        {getNumber}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

truffle-config.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const { INFURA_API_KEY, MNEMONIC } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
    },
    sepolia: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, INFURA_API_KEY),
      network_id: "11155111",
      gas: 8465030,
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: '0.8.2',
      parser: 'solcjs'
    }
  }
};
```

I had followed the exact same steps before (couple months ago) and it worked perfectly. Now when I try to recreate the same, it throws this error. I believe that the problem is because of some method deprecated in web3.js.  I went to the metamask official webpage to refer to their documentation. I tried changing web3.givenProvider to web3.currentProvider. I also tried couple more things but none worked. What changes do i have to do in my code to fix this ?  Please help me understand what the problem is and how the solution fixes it. Thanks in advance